# Using R transaction count for last 5 day by transaction account no by transaction currency

Tags: r

Suppose i have transactional data in the below format

```
 Tr_account.      Tr_date.     Tr_amount.    Tr_currency
 A01.             13.             2000.          Inr
 A01.             13.             3000.          Inr
 A01.             15.             1500.          Usd
 A02.             14.             6000.          Usd
 A02.             19.             7000.           Gbp
 A02.             14.             8000.           Inr
```

I want to get a table where I want to get last 5 days mean of transaction value by `tr_account` and by `tr_currency` in a single table in R.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(Tr_account.,Tr_currency) %>%
         arrange(Tr_account.,Tr_currency,Tr_date.)%>% 
         summarise(Avg = mean(tail(Tr_amount.,n=5),na.rm = TRUE))
```

Update: Using @MKR filter rule. We can find all transactions within 4 days then apply count

```
data %>% filter(Tr_date. >= max(Tr_date.)-4) %>%
         group_by(Tr_account.,Tr_currency) %>% summarise(N=n())
```

Comment: Can you use this to get count as well?

Comment: You can use `count` or any other function with `summarise` but what you want to count.

Comment: No of transactions in last 4 days for each tr ac no for each tr currency

Comment: Is this what you are looking for or No of trans in the last 4 days in each group

Answer (score 0):

To calculate `mean` for last `5` days it is important to find the `last` day and filter records which are with in previous 5 days from last date. This will take care of even multiple transactions on same day, which is very much expected.

A solution using `dplyr` can be as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Tr_date. = as.Date(Tr_date., format = "%d-%m-%Y")) %>%
  group_by(Tr_account., Tr_currency) %>%
  # All records from previous 5 days 
  filter(Tr_date. >= (max(Tr_date.)-5)) %>%
  summarise(Tr_amount. = mean(Tr_amount.))

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
# # Groups: Tr_account. [?]
#   Tr_account. Tr_currency Tr_amount.
#   <chr>       <chr>            <dbl>
# 1 A01.        Inr               2500
# 2 A01.        Usd               1500
# 3 A02.        Gbp               7000
# 4 A02.        Inr               8000
# 5 A02.        Usd               6000
```

**Data:**

***Note:*** Since, OP wants last 5 days mean hence, I have changed the `Tr_date.` column to represent date.

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Tr_account.      Tr_date.         Tr_amount.    Tr_currency
A01.             13-07-2018             2000.          Inr
A01.             13-07-2018             3000.          Inr
A01.             15-07-2018             1500.          Usd
A02.             14-07-2018             6000.          Usd
A02.             19-07-2018             7000.           Gbp
A02.             14-07-2018             8000.           Inr",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```